# CUDA для нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, cuda, c++

Кто-нибудь работал с технологией CUDA!? Как сложно написать код нейронной сети на C++ под CUDA? Какую видюху можно брать из соображения цена-качество!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В книжке Борескова есть в качестве приложения статья об опыте написания нейронной сети на CUDA.

Видюха - чем современнее, тем лучше. Дальше - по деньгам.

Answer (score 1):

Да в принципе несложно.

Можете посмотреть мои проекты нейронной библиотеки.

Последовательная версия https://github.com/NicholasShatokhin/OpenNNL

Версия на CUDA https://github.com/NicholasShatokhin/OpenNNLCuda

Answer (score 0):

В [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) модуль ML может использовать и CUDA и OpenCL